# How to make generic type information visible to Jackson's JSONSchema generator

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

Given a class with a Map property like:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();

    public Map<String, Double> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, Double> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

I wanted to see if the JSONSchema as produced by jackson framework's ObjectMapper can see the generic type of key=String and value=Double. Without any annotation, the JSONSchema only outputs it as Object.

Answer (score 0):

Due to type erasure, you need to use Jackson's [TypeReference class](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.2.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/type/TypeReference.html) to inform the ObjectMapper about the types. The "[3 Minute Tutorial](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind)" section on the Jackson page provides more information. You can also use the [@JsonSerialize and @JsonDeserialize](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.2.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/package-frame.html) annotations on the getter and setter to indicate the key and value types.